# Forest for linguistics - proportional alignment like in qtree

Tags: align, forest, tikz-qtree, qtree, vertical

I'm new to forest. Is there a style (or a modification of what's below) which produces the alignment of empty terminal nodes F3 and F4 in Tree A just like in Tree B?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
%\forestset{nice nodes/.style={for tree={inner sep=0pt,s sep=.2in,align=center, anchor=north}},default preamble=nice nodes, }
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\begin{document}

Tree A:

\begin{forest}
[
[DP, name=target[a labelled\\ subtree, roof]]  
[F$_4$P[F$_4$]
[F$_3$P[F$_3$]
[F$_2$P[F$_2$][\hspace{10pt}F$_1$P $\Rightarrow$ something, 
name=t[is there a way\\to move this label\\to the right?, roof]]]]]]]
\end{forest}

Tree B:

\begin{forest}
[
[DP, name=target[a labelled\\ subtree, roof]]  
[F$_4$P[F$_4$[$\emptyset$]]
[F$_3$P[F$_3$[]]
[F$_2$P[F$_2$][\hspace{10pt}F$_1$P $\Rightarrow$ something, 
name=t[I miss qtree, roof]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

A separate issue is the problem of moving a node label (F4P in the trees) to the right, so that it is not centered wrt to the node.
Here is what I get:

[image]

PS. The skeleton I'm using tolerates qtree and tikz-qtree but does not want to tolerate arrows in neither qtree nor tikz-qtree in XeLaTeX, so I'll need to stick to forest, I guess. That's why I'm trying to have a nice proportional tree in forest rather than using simply qtree.

Comment: You don't have any labels in your tree. Really confused.

Comment: @cfr -- I've edited the post. It should be clear now. "Labels" are the names of the nodes in the linguistic trees. The top-most node is the only one which I left unlabelled. Other labels in these two tree diarams are DP, F4P, F4, F3P, F3, F2P, F2, F1P=>something. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It is a bit confusing because, in Forest's terms, nodes can have `label`s, though yours do not :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for your main question, you probably just want to add `fit=band` to the tree.

[image: <code>fit=band</code>]

Note that `anchor=center` is default for `linguistics`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{
  nice nodes/.style={
    for tree={
      inner sep=0pt,
      fit=band,
    },
  },
  default preamble=nice nodes,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [
    [DP, name=target
      [nodes F$_3$ and F$_4$ do\\
      align appropriately\\
      (I think)\\
      wrt F$_2$, roof
      ]
    ]
    [F$_4$P
      [F$_4$]
      [F$_3$P
        [F$_3$]
        [F$_2$P
          [F$_2$]
          [\hspace{10pt}F$_1$P$\Rightarrow$something, name=t
            [is there a way\\to move this label\\to the right?, roof
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I'm not quite sure what you want to shift where. What you are calling the node `label` is actually not a `label`, but the node `content`. Nodes can have `label`s and `content`s, so this may be a source of confusion.

You can shift the node at the bottom right right (or left). However, I'm not sure if that is really what you mean.

```
            [is there a way\\to move this label\\to the right?, roof, xshift=10pt
            ]
```

[image: shifted right]

To avoid a lopsided roof, we can redefine the `edge path`.

[image: fix roof]

```
            [is there a way\\to move this label\\to the right?, xshift=10pt, edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) ++(5pt,0) -- (.north east) -- (.north west) -- cycle}
            ]
```

If you need this a lot, a style would be convenient.

```
  shift with roof/.style={
    xshift=#1,
    edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) ++(#1/2,0) -- (.north east) -- (.north west) -- cycle}
  },
```

Then we can write just

```
            [is there a way\\to move this label\\to the right?, shift with roof=10pt
            ]
```

to produce the same output as above.

You can make the top less 'pointy' by increasing the distance between the root's children. Possibly a bit extreme:

[image: less 'pointy']

```
  [, s sep'+=20pt
```

A bit less extreme may be better.

[image: less extreme]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{
  nice nodes/.style={
    for tree={
      inner sep=0pt,
      fit=band,
    },
  },
  default preamble=nice nodes,
  shift with roof/.style={
    xshift=#1,
    edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) ++(#1/2,0) -- (.north east) -- (.north west) -- cycle}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [, s sep'+=10pt
    [DP, name=target
      [nodes F$_3$ and F$_4$ do\\
      align appropriately\\
      (I think)\\
      wrt F$_2$, roof
      ]
    ]
    [F$_4$P
      [F$_4$]
      [F$_3$P
        [F$_3$]
        [F$_2$P
          [F$_2$]
          [\hspace{10pt}F$_1$P$\Rightarrow$something, name=t
            [is there a way\\to move this label\\to the right?, shift with roof=10pt
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This works! Btw, I did manage to add an annotation to the left of the node label (="content" in forest termiology) by using node[right] in the `\draw` command -- the solution taken directly from the last page of this: (http://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/003391), as shown in my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @oliver Wouldn't `label=right:annotation` be easier?

Comment: I don't know. Can you please modify my code below with this? I'll see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: @oliver Just add `label=right:annotation` as an option to the node you want annotated. It will just get passed to Ti*k*Z's `label` when the node is constructed.

Comment: Excellent! It works. Indeed, a more comfortable option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  nice nodes/.style={
    for tree={
      inner sep=1pt, s sep=12pt,
      fit=band,
    },
  },
  default preamble=nice nodes,
}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
 [
 [DP, name=target[nodes F$_3$ and F$_4$ do\\ not align vertically\\ wrt           F$_2$, roof]]  
 [F$_4$P[F$_4$]    [F$_3$P[F$_3$]
  [F$_2$P[F$_2$]    [F$_1$P, name=t[I miss qtree, roof]] 
{ \draw (.east) node[right]{$\Rightarrow$ \textit{adjective}}; } ]]]]]
   %\draw[->] (t) to[out=south west,in=south] (target);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Which give me this:

[image]