# forest respecify branch positions

Tags: forest

[image: example tree]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [VP
    [DP]
      [V'       
        [{A B C\textcolor{white}{A B C}}
         [xxx] ]
        [DP]
      ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Most similar question: [Forest for linguistics - proportional alignment like in qtree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361148/forest-for-linguistics-proportional-alignment-like-in-qtree?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Hi, I'm new to forest and qtree. I've looked through the docs but this question doesn't seem to come up in the diagrams as an option.

I would like the line coming down from V' to point to say 'A' in 'ABC', and the branch downwards to come from say 'C', rather than the inwards and outwards lines both going through and from the mid point.

I've managed to do a hack to get the down-line coming out from C, but then this also messes up the line above.

Hopefully there is a quick win.

Comment: full MWE please.

Comment: now edited to make MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

with "dirty trick" combining `forest` and `tikz` drawing:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}%
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
inner xsep=0pt,
s sep=9mm,
l sep=7mm}
    [VP
    [DP]
      [V'
        [A, name=a]
        [DP]
      ]
]
\begin{scope}[inner xsep=0pt, node distance=7mm and 0mm]
\node (b) [right=of a] {B};
\node (c) [right=of b] {C};
\node (x) [below=of c] {XXX};
\draw (c) -- (x);
\end{scope}
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ah, and if I wanted the tree to continue growing from "XXX" in forest mode?

Comment: about this ask new question. your comment is new question, and such here is not visible to many people.

Comment: ok, [done here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436524/forest-respecify-branch-positions)

Comment: @A.D I think you mean https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436566/15925

Comment: This doesn't really get the spacing right, because the space taken by the 'B' and 'C' are not accounted for when the tree is packed. @A.D