# forest respecify branch positions 2

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

following on from [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436524/forest-respecify-branch-positions)

Example Problem:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}%
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
inner xsep=0pt,
s sep=9mm,
l sep=7mm}
    [VP
    [DP]
      [V'
        [A, name=a]
        [DP]
      ]
]
\begin{scope}[inner xsep=0pt, node distance=7mm and 0mm]
\node (b) [right=of a] {B};
\node (c) [right=of b] {C};
\node (x) [below=of c] {XXX};
\draw (c) -- (x);
\end{scope}
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

XXX is now below ABC but if I want to do these sort of rearrangements at multiple levels (e.g. XXX now should point to the 1 in 123 in a node at a level below, and the 3 then points to node below it, can I do it in forest, or do I need to manually build the tree in tikz?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKXLl.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that all within forest without having to resort to place extra stuff with Ti*k*Z methods. One possibility is to play with anchors, note that there are different anchors: node anchors, child anchors and parent anchors.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}%
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
inner xsep=0pt,
s sep=9mm,
l sep=7mm}
    [VP
    [DP]
      [V'
        [ABC, name=a,parent anchor=-45
         [XXX,anchor=135]]
        [DP]
      ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The numbers are just angles. In order to make `V'` connect to `A` in `ABC` just add `,child anchor=120`.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}%
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
inner xsep=0pt,
s sep=9mm,
l sep=7mm}
    [VP
    [DP]
      [V'
        [ABC, name=a,parent anchor=-45,child anchor=120
         [XXX,anchor=135]]
        [DP]
      ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you choose those numbers, and also show how to get the edge from V' to land at A in the ABC?

Comment: @AndrewSwann The numbers are just angles and I added this feature as well. (I was too sloppy and did not read this requirement.)

Comment: And to get the line vertical it is important that "anchor - parent anchor = 180"

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes and no. In this case yes, because both nodes have the same width, but in general no. However, you can also adjust the `grow` direction on the way as detailed on p. 42 of the forest manual. Of course, you can completely change the layout, but then I guess the OP needs to slightly rephrase the question.